# How to split the array elements in bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

In bash scripting, I have an array say `arr=("element1" "element2" "element3")`. How to print the output as
`element 1 element 2 element 3`

So,How to add spaces between strings and digits for each array element?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. There are no spaces in the array, what do you want to remove? Show how you used `tr` and what the output was.

Comment: In a bash script, the array should look like this `arr=("element1" "element2" "element3")`

Comment: When assigning arrays in bash, elements need to be separated by spaces, not commas; I think you want `arr=("element1" "element2" "element3")` for the assignment. But I'm also confused about what you're trying to do with the array. From the example, it looks like you want to *add* spaces (like "element1" -> "element 1"), but that doesn't match your description.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. yes I want the output like "element1" -> "element 1"

Comment: For instance, how would the output look for an array consisting of the two elements `(abc34def56  4711)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear about what exactly you want.

If the keyword is only literally `element`, can try:

```
echo ${arr[*]} | sed -E 's/(element)/\1 /g'
```

1. print out array as string
2. replace `element` with `element`  (tailed with space)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I was asked this question in an interview. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`echo` outputs its parameters with **one** space in between. Hence just doing

```
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

is sufficient. If you know for sure, that the array elements don't contain spaces,

```
echo ${arr[@]}
```

would do as well - but why take a risk?

If you want to have **more than one space** in between, you can use `printf`. Say you want 3 spaces between the elements. This would then be

```
printf "%s   " "${arr[@]}"; echo
```

The final, lone `echo` just produces the newline character. Note however that this use of `printf` has the effect of also adding 3 spaces **after the last element** as well. If this troubles you, you can strip it:

```
printf "%s   " "${arr[@]}" | sed 's/...$//'; echo
```

or, if you have GNU `head` (for instance, if you are on Linux), by

```
printf "%s   " "${arr[@]}" | head -c -3; echo
```

(the options `-c -3` tell `head` to drop the last 3 characters).